# In JMeter script how to pic a random item from drop down list

Tags: jmeter

I had a scenario like I need to select one random date range from drop down list of values(like today, yesterday, last month etc). How should i select one value randomly every time from the drop down list.waht function or method i need use in my jmeter script.Any one please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to provide more details, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: my understanding of this issue is that, you need to correlate report and dates. Try keeping both report names and its dates as 2 columns in a CSV file and use http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config. and refer values using column name. whenever a report is picked by first column, corresponding date will be picked from second column.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this done is using [HTML Link Parser](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTML_Link_Parser), refer [Poll Example](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#poll_example) user manual entry for more details, basically you need to provide input name and a wildcard like `.*` and JMeter will automatically scan the possible options and pick up a random value.

Other option (if the above one is not applicable for some reason) is using [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) or [CSS/JQuery Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) to get the possible dropdown values from the page [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp), `Match No.` parameter set to `0` will return the random option value.